# Read only access to stored procedure contents

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to set up SQL Server to give developers read-only access to the contents of stored procedures on our production database?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can grant them the `VIEW DEFINITION` privilege to those procs.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808.aspx) for what this privilege does.

You can apply `VIEW DEFINITION` at different scopes:

- Server
- Database
- Schema
- Individual entities (e.g. a proc, a function, a view)

You can also use a query to generate a script for many procs.
So if you have a user `Bob`:

```
SELECT N'GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON '
    + QUOTENAME(SPECIFIC_SCHEMA)
    + N'.'
    + QUOTENAME(SPECIFIC_NAME)
    + N' TO Bob;'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```

that will give you something like this, which you can then run:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[aspnet_RegisterSchemaVersion] TO Bob;
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion] TO Bob;
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[aspnet_Applications_CreateApplication] TO Bob;
...
```

Comment: Are there any alternatives to setting it per stored procedure? I was hoping for a method that didn't require that each proc be modified.

Comment: If you add a new proc, you still need to do the same grant. Is there a way to grant a user view permission to stored procs at a database level?

Answer (score 16):

Example of granting `VIEW DEFINITION` at the **Schema** scope/level for **dbo**.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION
ON schema::[dbo]
TO Bob;
```

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

I needed to grant access to a domain account.. syntax for this was

grant view definition on schema :: [dbo] to "domain\BOB"

Answer (score 5):

**DB Name --> Security --> Users --> Right Click User name --> Properties --> select Securables --> Click Search --> select All Objects of type --> Check Stored Procedures --> Check View Definition --> OK.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While i know this is late in response to the question, but for those people that have come here looking for an answer (just as I did a few minutes ago) in at least SQL management studio 2014 you can edit the user account and edit the permissions in the SECURABLES area and tick all the boxes in VIEW that you want them to have access to.

This does the above without having to run scripts.

Comment: That's preferred solution. To be more specific about the question above, grant "View any definition".

Answer (score 1):

My variant for all db procedures:

```
select 'GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name +
       '] TO ' + '[domain\username]'
  from sys.all_objects
 where type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
   and schema_id <> schema_id('sys')
```