# sql server database instance permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running SQL Server 2012 and want to set up permissions on an instance on it. I want to grant permissions to an active directory group to be able to do the following

- Connect to the SQL Server instance via management studio
- Access all databases on the server
- View all the tables, stored procs, views, functions etc on the instance
- Ability to run select queries against any database
- But not be able to alter, create or change anything in any of the datatabase

Is this possible - how could I configure it to achieve such?

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of your requirements by giving public access to the instance, public permissions and db_datareader to each database.  The tricky part is allowing them to view each stored procedure and function.  SQLMenace posted an answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533084/read-only-access-to-stored-procedure-contents).
Basically, he uses dynamic sql to grant permission to the stored procedures one at a time.  You'll need to do the same for functions.

```
select 'GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON ' + quotename(specific_schema) 
+ '.' + quotename(specific_name)
+ ' TO ' + 'BOB'
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Unfortunately, these permissions will need to be added to each new SP and function that is added to each database.